# PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, android-preferences

Добрый день, сегодня полезла я разбираться в первый раз с `PreferenceActivity`. Создала класс, сделала его наследником преференс активити, переопределила метод 
`onCreate`...а вот поключить разметку внутри этого метода не могу. Метод `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settingsone)` появляется зачеркнутый.

Это ведь значит, что этот метод устарел и его использовать нельзя? Я просто новичок в программировании и первый раз столкнулась с зачеркиванием методов. И если так, то какой метод использовать для подключения xml-файла?

```
public class PreferenceApp extends PreferenceActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settingsone);



    }// end method onCreate
}// end class PreferenceApp
```

Answer (score 2):

Если вы не используете фрагменты, то можете спокойно проигнорировать этот `deprecation`, если вера не позволяет видеть зачеркнутый метод - тогда переходите на использование фрагментов, а именно `PreferenceFragment`, которые по сути являются рекомендованным паттерном разработки.